# Show dynamic titles for tables in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitableview, sdk, nsmutablearray

I have an array with events. All these events are shown in a UITableView. How can I set a new section title each time a new event date is printed?

```
E.g.:

20.12.2012
- event 1
- event 2
- event 4

21.12.2012:
- event 3

22.12.2012:
-event 5
```

This is how my Event object looks like:

```
events = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];

Event *e1 = [[Event alloc] init];
e1.date = @"20.12.2012";
e1.time = @"15:00 Uhr";
e1.address = @"Bla";
[events addObject:e1];

Event *e2 = [[Event alloc] init];
e2.date = @"20.12.2012";
e2.time = @"16:00 Uhr";
e2.address = @"Bla";
[events addObject:e2];

Event *e3 = [[Event alloc] init];
e3.date = @"20.12.2012";
e3.time = @"16:30 Uhr";
e3.address = @"Bla";
[events addObject:e3];

Event *e4 = [[Event alloc] init];
e4.date = @"21.12.2012";
e4.time = @"17:30 Uhr";
e4.address = @"Bla";
[events addObject:e4];
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe it is not really the best title for your question?

Comment: Provide a better one and I'll change it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save all your events to a dictionary which has dates as keys.

Assume you have `_eventsDictionary` and `_events` as ivar in your header(.h) file. `NSMutableDictionary *_eventsDictionary;` `NSArray *_events`

```
- (void)reloadTableData {
   _eventsDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
   for (Event *ev in _events) {
        NSMutableArray *eventArray = [_eventsDictionary objectForKey:ev.date];
        if (! eventArray) {
            // first event for this date
            eventArray = [NSMutableArray array];
            [_eventsDictionary setObject:eventArray forKey:ev.date];
        }
        [eventArray addObject:ev];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Now you have all events in arrays, which are in `_eventsDictionary`.

```
- (NSString *)dateStringAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
   // Actually I prefer sort them as date objects
// Since you have all dates as string, it should ok for you
   NSArray *allSortedKeys = [[_eventsDictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

   return [allSortedKeys objectAtIndex:index];
}
- (NSArray *)eventsArrayAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {

   NSArray *eventsArray = [_eventDictionary objectForKey:[self dateStringAtIndex:index]];
   return eventsArray;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return _eventDictionary.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

   return [[self eventsArrayAtIndex:section] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 return [self dateStringAtIndex:section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   cell = .....
   .....

    NSArray *eventsArray = [self eventsArrayAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    Event *ev = [eventsArray objectAtIndex.row];
    // configure your cell with the event
    // eg. cell.textLabel.text = ev.time
    return cell;
}
```

Now you can call [self reloadTableData] somewhere after you have the events in you events array and it makes the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Count the number of unique dates across all events;
2. Implement

   ```
   -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
      return numberOfUniqueDates;
   }
   ```
3. Implement

   ```
   -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
       return [eventsData[section] count];
   }
   ```
4. On

   ```
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

       Use indexPath.section and indexPath.row to determine the values for cells;
   }
   ```
5. Implement

   ```
   - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
       return date[section];
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add

```
 [yourTableView reloadData];
```

after you update the content of the tableView...